# How do I insert to multiple tables using active record

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I would like to add some values into multiple tables, but right now my code isnt that good. I have commented out the values id like to add to which tables.

the controller called Add_employee

```
public function addemp() 
{   
    //id like to add this to 'employees'
    $data1 = array( 
    'emp_no' => $this->input->post('emp_no'),
    'birth_date' => $this->input->post('birth_date'),
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
    'hire_date' => $this->input->post('hire_date'),
    );

    //idd like to add this to 'titles'
    $data2 = array(
    'emp_no' => $this->input->post('emp_no'),
    'title' => $this->input->post('title')
    );

    //idd like to add this to 'dept_emp' and id like to add value 'emp_no' to the table 'salaries'
    $data3 = array(
    'emp_no' => $this->input->post('emp_no'),
    'dept' => $this->input->post('dept')
    );

    $mdata ['m1'] = $data1;
    $mdata ['m2'] = $data2;
    $mdata ['m3'] = $data3;

    $this->add_model->adddata($mdata);
    $this->load->view('add_view', $data1);
}
```

the model called Add_model

```
public function adddata($data) {

    //extract();
    $this->db->insert('employees', $m1);
    $this->db->insert('titles', $m2);
    $this->db->insert('dept_emp', $m3);
    //$this->db->insert('salaries', $emp_no);//$emp_no => 'emp_no');

    return;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error. If so please post it here.....I think you need initialize $mdata = array(); before assigning data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

### In Controller

```
public function addemp() 
{
    $data1 = array(...);
    $data2 = array(...);
    $data3 = array(...);

    $mdata['employees'] = $data1;
    $mdata['titles'] = $data2;
    $mdata['dept_emp'] = $data3;

    $this->load->model('add_model'); // If not auto loaded then load it first
    if($this->add_model->adddata($mdata))
    {
        // do something after successful insert
    }
    else
    {
        // something went wrong, all not inserted
    }
}
```

### In Model

```
public function adddata($data) {
    $inserted=0;
    foreach($data as $k=>$v) $inserted+=(int)$this->db->insert($k, $data[$k]);
    if($inserted===count($data)) return true; // all inserted
    return false; // all not inserted
}
```

Comment: Great, that works, although a little complicated for me. Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: @AziebAssres, There are other ways but this one is easiest one I think. Also there is a function `insert_batch()` which inserts more than one record but applies to one table.